Can Classical Logic Handle Conditionals whose Antecedents are Contingent
Consider the following statements: One: If all Xs are cats, then all Xs are mammals. Two: If all Xs are prime, then all Xs are divisible by themselves and 1. One of the reasons that both of these statements are true is because their antecedents are false. However, why are their antecedents false? Because to me it seems their antecedents are contingently false or true depending on what we specify as the domain of discourse. Which brings me to the question of whether Classical Logic can handle conditionals whose antecedents are contingently true or false? And can we use Modus Ponens on a contingent antecedent so as to derive the conclusion in a conditional?

In classical logic the conditional is rightly coined as material conditional, then contemplate materiality vs contingency philosophically...

The picture is a cat. Is the picture a mammal? All whole numbers are divisable by themselves & one.

@CriglCragl, no, because the first statement is false.

Yes it can. Conditionals wouldn't be much use if they could not accommodate contingent operands. And modus ponens works in classical logic.
You are correct to say that the domain of discourse makes a difference. If our domain of discourse is everything that exists then your antecedent, "all Xs are cats" is false. If the domain is specified to be my nextdoor neighbour's pets, then "all Xs are cats" is true and so, "If all Xs are cats, then all Xs are mammals" is true, but not trivially.
An extra finesse is that the counterfactual, "If all Xs were cats, then all Xs would be mammals" is true on many accounts, but not trivially.

Sure. You just wind up with a contingent expression as the output. Exactly like doing algebra; you manipulate according to rules that are correct for all values of the variables, then discuss the result in contingent terms. If that means your answer is contingent -- a formula -- rather than a single value, that's all you can get until the inputs are better resolved.
It may still be useful, by helping to determine which contingent inputs really don't affect the final result, or you may be able to derive a simplified description.
